# TPU: Is there a way to use a Coral USB Accelerator in android device?

Tags: android, usb, accelerator, tpu, google-coral

I want to use USB Coral accelerator in Android Device to use CNN in my Android applications.
Is it available to use? If you guys to know it. Please Let me know.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, using the accelerator on an Android Device is not officially supported :/

Comment: Have you heard about any recent developments on this subject ?

Answer (score 0):

An unreleased Android is working in the lab on the Coral Dev Board.  That will not help anyone run the USB Accelerator on an arbitrary Android phone or tablet because Android has a lot of security features.  Only certain types of USB controllers are allowed.  It requires significant modification of the Android OS software to enable this kind of communication.  It requires security changes and NNAPI operation-- simply put it's impossible to plug in anything beyond simple accessories on Android phones without having complete control of the OS.

For people designing their own hardware, where they have full control over the system, it is possible to run the edge TPU with Android.  NXP is releasing an Android 9 for the Coral Dev Board with edge TPU support.